# Does javascript resolve variables within function definitions before execution?

Tags: javascript, html

If *one.js* happens to finish loading before *two.js* even gets parsed, will *x* exist? Surely this is possible because once an asynchronous script has been loaded, it's immediately executed and blocks further parsing of the HTML file. Thereby blocking *two.js* before it defines *x*.

To my knowledge, JavaScript doesn't need to resolve variables within a function. Instead, it waits until the function is executed to determine it's existence. Since *x.prt* isn't used until the window and it's resources (including *two.js*) have loaded, it should be safe load both scripts asynchronously, right?

**jsfiles.html:**

```
...
<script src="lib/one.js" type="text/javascript" async="async"></script>
<script src="lib/two.js" type="text/javascript" async="async"></script>
...
```

**one.js:**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    x.prt("Will this print 100% of the time?");
}, false);
```

**two.js**

```
var x = {
    prt: function(str) {
        console.log(str + " Or will this definition not be seen?");
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code in a web browser?

Comment: It works. But I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't attempt to evaluate anything inside a function until the function executes. It will not attempt to look up `x` until the function executes, at which point `x` will exist as a global variable.

> If one.js happens to finish loading before two.js even gets parsed, will x exist?

No, but it doesn't matter, because you don't need `x` to exist to **define** a function which uses `x`. `x` **will** exist by the time your window's load callback fires and your callback tries to use `x`.

Comment: As a side question... Is there a benefit to using the var keyword in the global scope?